# How to specify the type of arguments given to Algebraic type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

If I have an Algebraic Data Type  like below

```
data BinaryTree a = Leaf 
                    | Node a (BinaryTree a ) (BinaryTree a)
                    deriving (Eq,Ord)
```

Here Leaf is for empty and a is the node and the other two parameters are for subtrees coming from the node.

Is there a way I can specify that the argument a should be deriving `Show`

I was trying to give my own implementation of Show for `BinaryTree` , and I started out simple like:

```
instance Show (BinaryTree a) where
    show Leaf = "x"
    show (Node node left right) =  show node++ "\n" ++ show left ++"  "++show right
```

But `show node` doesn't work -> `No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only work with `show node`, if `node` is of a type that is a member of the `Show` typeclass. You thus should add a type constraint in the head of the `instance` declaration:

```
--         ↓ type constraint
instance Show a => Show (BinaryTree a) where
    show Leaf = "x"
    show (Node node left right) =  show node ++ '\n' : show left ++ "  "++show right
```